# Command '' not found + virtualenvwrapper error on ssh login (Ubuntu 18.04 x64)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualenv

when logging into my VPS with ssh keys, I get this:

```
Command '' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install libpam-mount      
...           
sudo apt install nmh               

virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Here's my `.bashrc` variables:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Env
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

## What I've tried

- Sourcing `.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` (no errors)
- Upgrading `virtualenvwrapper` with `pip3 --upgrade` (latest)

Also, my virtualenv's work perfectly.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` to your .bashrc just before you source virtualenvwrapper.sh, that might give you a hint of what might be going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by rearranging the exports to this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Env
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 12):

In **lines 47-51** of the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script, it first checks to see if the environment variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` is set, and if not, it sets it in **line 50**:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
```

The problem is that newer versions of Ubuntu (18.04+) no longer come with the binary `python` installed, only `python3`. Change `python` to `python3` in **line 50** of the script and you're all set ;)

Otherwise, in `.bashrc`, you need to **first** set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` and then `source` the script:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is part of a Python package.

I ran into this on a new Ubuntu 18.04 installation.  I checked my logs on an older machine and found the following:

```
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
sudo -H pip  install virtualenvwrapper
```

When I ran them on the new machine, the error message went away.